# How do I stop entire content of my DB from showing when backspace is used in search box?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a livesearch feature. If I click inside the search field and hit backspace(delete button on my MAC) until the searchbox is empty, when the searchbox is clear every entry in my database shows.

**Here is search form code:**

```
    <head>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchq()
        {
            var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
            $.post("search.php" , {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {$("#output").html(output)});
        }     
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="search.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for members..."   onkeyup="searchq();" autofocus/>
            <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
        </form>

        <div id="output">

        </div>    
    </body>
```

**Here is PHP code:**

```
//collect
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {

    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    //sanitize
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $searchq);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Tutorials WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR artist LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);//counts number of rows in table

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'No search results';
    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $tit = $row['title'];
            $art = $row['artist'];
            $prev = $row['preview'];
            $wat = $row['watch'];

            $output .='<div class="searchdiv"> <b>'.$tit.' </b>- '.$art.' <br> <a   href="'.$prev.'" >preview tutorial</a> - <a href="'.$wat.'">watch full tutorial</a></div>';      
        }
        //echo "<p> " .$count. " search results</p>";
    }    
}
echo($output);
?>
```

Code is very novice, I know.

Comment: Put an `if` statement around `$.post(` that checks for a blank value in your search box.

Comment: Add a requirement that the length of the search string must be at least one character before displaying results.

Comment: don't allow a `like '%%'` query, then. check if there's anything to search for in the first place. after all, sql is a language where the less you specify, the more you get.

Comment: or add space to preg_replace: `[^0-9a-z ]`. EDIT: min-length (as suggested by Qirel) is the best choice, I'd say

Comment: You might want to also not search if 'stop words' are supplied in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

I would add:

```
if ($searchq == "") {
$output = 'No search results';
}else{
query here...
}
```

That way you don't send empty searches to the query.